# UPDATE и SELECT, как правильно поступить?

Tags: php, mysql

есть 2 таблицы:
первая

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
    `idorder` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `amount` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` ENUM('processing','declined','approved','transfering') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'processing',
    `user_wallet` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User_wallet_is_unknown',
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idorder`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=21
;
```

вторая:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
    `idorders` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_idorder` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `order_date` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` ENUM('Processing','Declined','Approved') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `secret_code` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `wallets_idwallets` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_wallet` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sum_to_buyer` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sum_for_us` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `create_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `paid_status` ENUM('paid','unpaid') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unpaid',
    `paid_wallet` VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknowWallet',
    `paid_sum` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idorders`),
    INDEX `fk_orders_wallets_idx` (`wallets_idwallets`),
    INDEX `order_idorder` (`order_idorder`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_order` FOREIGN KEY (`order_idorder`) REFERENCES `order` (`idorder`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_wallets` FOREIGN KEY (`wallets_idwallets`) REFERENCES `wallets` (`idwallets`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=106
;
```

делаю запрос UPDATE:

```
UPDATE `order`
SET `status` = 'transfering'
WHERE `idorder` = (
  SELECT
   `idorder`
  FROM (
    SELECT
      `o`.`idorder`,
      `o`.`amount`,
      (
        SELECT
          SUM(`sum_for_us`)
        FROM `orders` AS os
        WHERE
          `os`.`order_idorder` = `idorder` AND
          `os`.`paid_status` = 'paid' AND
          `os`.`status` = 'processing'
      ) as `paid_sum`
    FROM `order` AS o
  )a
  WHERE `paid_sum` = `amount`
)
```

если возвращается 1 значение то UPDATE работает как надо, но бывает же и так что заказов более одного и тогда UPDATE уже не работает, подскажите как решить проблему такого рода?Может выбрать вначале значения а потом UPDATE в цикле прогнать уже на PHP, а может както можно в запросе к бд это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно всегда чтобы выбирало только 1 результат то добавьте в селект `LIMIT 1`.

Eсли нужно чтоб обновляло все строки которые выбрал селект то замените `WHERE idorder=(<select here>)` на `WHERE idorder IN (<select here>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сначала записать ответ, а потом отправить все